# Wrap Android EditText when text change programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

My EditText  wraps only when I do scroll manually or when I call
editTextAppDescription.requestLayout(); programmatically.

It is essential to know that I do editTextAppDescription.append("..my text..");

Below is my xml code :

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ffffffff">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewAppLogo"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/loading" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewAppTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageViewAppLogo"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewAppLogo"
                android:text="App Title ..."
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewAppDeveloper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textViewAppTitle"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewAppLogo"
                android:text="App Developer ..." />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/installButton"
                style="@style/install_button_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewAppLogo"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/install_button_shape"
                android:text="@string/installApp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/openAppButton"
                style="@style/install_button_text"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewAppLogo"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/install_button_shape"
                android:text="@string/openApp"
                android:visibility="gone" />


                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                    style="@style/CustomProgressBar"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="5dp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/installButton"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/installButton"
                    android:layout_below="@id/imageViewAppLogo"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:indeterminate="true"
                    android:indeterminateOnly="false"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/separator"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="3dip"
                android:layout_below="@+id/installButton"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow" >

            </View>


        </RelativeLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scollViewScreenShots"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutBody"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollViewScreenshots"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/scgreen">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutScreenShots"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="320dip"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextAppDescription"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="50dip"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:background="#00000000" />
                <Button 
                    android:id="@+id/buttonReadmore"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Readmore"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>



    </LinearLayout>
```

My EditText (editTextAppDescription) display only 50dp when text change programmitically inpite of having: android:layout_height="wrap_content" !

How can I make it (editTextAppDescription) expand when text changes?

Comment: didn't get your question..

Comment: My EditText (textViewAppDescription) display only 50dp when text change programmitically inpite of having: android:layout_height="wrap_content" !

Comment: try setting singleLine="false"

Comment: Sorry, it's a read only editText

Comment: what do you mean by "read only" ?

Comment: I set appDescription.setKeyListener(null); to make it non editable

Comment: there is no need of EditText then, useTextView instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69121/discussion-between-yassiner89-and-murtaza-hussain).